# What does it mean when a directory is red in IntelliJ WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

So I pressed something by mistake (was in a flyout menu so not sure what it was) and now one of my folders is red.
[image: red directory]

This is what a regular directory looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means *Excluded Root* and is explained in [IntelliJ IDEA Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/content-root.html) as:

> Excluded roots are ones that IntelliJ IDEA "partially ignores".
>
> Very limited coding assistance is provided for files in excluded
>   folders. Classes contained in excluded folders don't appear in code
>   completion suggestion lists, references to such classes are shown in
>   the editor as unresolved. When searching, IntelliJ IDEA doesn't look
>   in excluded folders, etc.

[Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/symbols.html) is a complete list of IntelliJ symbols and icons for future reference.

You can cancel the exclusion by right clicking the directory in project view and selecting *Mark Directory As/Cancel Exclusion*.

Comment: Thanks! A coworker helped me with this, too - but your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

As a side note, if the folder itself is "grey" but the directory name is "red" apparently that means <strike>"a git root" or some odd.</strike> update: it's actually brown and means "unversioned - File exists locally, but is not in the repository, and is not scheduled for adding." see the key [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/file-status-highlights.html).  If you're using the "night" theme then it shows up as looking *way closer to red than brown*.

[image: red text]